# Splunk unable to lookups

Tags: lookup, splunk

I want to filter the search by matching IP address to subnet masks.
I extracted the ip_address field.

I created lookup table file named AP-Subnet.csv

```
subnets,ap
10.24.0.0/14,YES
163.243.193.0/24,YES
10.120.250.0/24,YES
10.124.248.0/21,YES
```

Then I created lookup definition AP_subnet_lookups

[image: lookup definition AP_subnet_lookups]

This is my search

```
sourcetype="logs" |transaction ip_address |lookup AP_subnet_lookups subnets |table eventcount ip_address hostname
```

The search result contains other ip addresses that doesn't match the masks.

How should I change my search?

Answer (score 1):

Set `match_type = CIDR(subnets)` in [`transforms.conf`](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/admin/transformsconf).

Your `transforms.conf` is probably located in `$SPLUNK_HOME/etc/apps/search/local/` if you modified your lookup via GUI while within the search app.

If you can't find it then locate it using `./splunk cmd btool transforms list --debug`.